# Page references updating

Tags: microsoft-word

I am using Word 2010 and would like to be able to attach a reference (Page No.) in a Workbook and be able to update a reference to the page number in a second document eg a facilitator guide.
I would like it to be similar to update the table of contents, but between two documents.

e.g.
In the draft workbook I have an activity on P5
I would like to reference P5 in the facilitator guide (Refer participants to P5 in their workbook)
During subsequent amendments to the workbook, the page number for the activity is now P35
How can I update my page reference in the facilitator guide to update with the new Page number (P35)?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to add a cross-reference to an item that is in another document is to combine the documents into a "master document". This functionality is hidden fairly well, but a very useful [tutorial can be found here](http://www.howtogeek.com/73960/create-a-master-document-in-word-2010-from-multiple-documents/). A word of warning, however: many have found the Master Document functionality to be [prone to document corruption](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/are-master-documents-safe-in-word-2010/f72b4e7b-a658-49fc-a43c-a540f0e41b13), so UAYOR.